# Document Library Created Using Template Shows Field Internal Name

Tags: document-library, content-type, site-column, document-template

I have created a Document Library Template using "***Save as template***" option from library settings page.

When I create a new document library using that template it shows a site columns internal name instead of display name.

The template source document library is using Content Type containing a site column **Document Category**. This **Document Category** column has internal name **AbcDocCat**

So, overall the new document library shows column with **AbcDocCat** instead of **Document Category**, and this is the issue.

**SharePoint Environment:** Office 365 SharePoint

Any resolution?

**Update 1:**
(1) I created site column with name **AbcDocCat** and later renamed to **Document Category**, to keep internal name clear.
(2) The field name appears in ContentType as **Document Category**, so this could not be cause of issue.
(3) The ContentType is at site collection level and not at Content Type Hub

Comment: ContentTypes are copies of its parents. When you click up through the ContentType parents, when is the name incorrect and when correct? List►Site►Site Collection►ContentTypeHub

Comment: I have updated, please check.

Comment: I think that may happen if the Template was created from another language than the one you use to create the new list (I mean the UI language of the site).

Comment: @Evariste Yes, this could be reason, I have setup different language for myself whereas the site uses German language. Could you please suggest how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that may happen if the template was created from another language than the one you use to create the new list (I mean the UI language of the site).

You should first populate the fields titles at the content type level for every language set on your site (do this by switching the UI language and then edit the field title as usual).

Then re-create the Template, and test it.

Comment: I just check and found it needs to be fixed for that language. Thanks.